# User Agents in e-mail Headers

Tags: web-application

I received a COX e-mail generated on a Surface tablet. The User Agent was exactly what I expected it to be: Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 10.0 ETC. Then I received an AOL email with User Agent: JAS STD. I was told it was generated on the same Surface as the first e-mail. Is that possible?

Comment: All headers could theoretically be chanced on all servers the mail gets relayed on. So, if AOL chooses to replace the user agent for all their outgoing mail, they should not, but easily can.